# Bash For Loop for Diff of Current & Previous Output

Tags: arrays, json, bash, math

trying to flesh out a bash script where i have a file with a json array, lets say its 5elements. running a command with against each element, returns a highest & lowest values of that element eg.

```
{
array="[1, 2, ..., 5]"
}
```

the command running through the array, returns a high & a low value, like following json

```
{
[
  0.3216,
  1478.4,
  0.3215,
  17669.5,
  0.3214
],
[
  0.3217,
  90.2,
  0.3218,
  4785.3,
  0.3219
]
}
```

on each element, i need to perform some simple maths, the lowest - highest = result. The values are coming back as tiny decimals in sci notation eg. 1e-08

this is simple enough, but then i'd also like to keep calculating & printing the current value, until stopped every 30 seconds, along with the difference of the last value ie. so the current value - the previous value.

so first loop would print current value & diff which would be 0, then 30 seconds later would print next current value & diff of the last. output not a huge deal but they'll most likely be tiny decimals in sci notation.
having a bit of a fail trying to store those values nicely in a current for loop, and to diff vs a previous loop, or how to do it properly... whats the best approach?

```
function diff()
{
    for a in ${array}; 
        do
            high="$(some cmd${a}" #cmd to return highest val of a
            eg. high=0.3216
            low="$(some cmd${a}"  #cmd to return lowest of a
            #eg.low=0.3217

            current="$(awk -v a="$low" -v b="$high" 'BEGIN{print (a - b)}' > value.txt)"

            prev="$(cat value.txt)"
            
            diff="$(awk -v a="$current" -v b="$prev" 'BEGIN{print (a - b)}')"

            TIME="$(date +%T)"
            echo "$TIME" "$current" "$diff"
        done
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts; please do mention samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: The so-called JSON you posted isn't valid. `array=` should be `"array":` and in the other codeblock key-names are missing entirely. So, to get this right; for the first array, you want to print the current time, the outcome of `0.3214 - 17669.5` and `0`? Why the `0` if it's always `0`?